# Android webview: JavaScript halts on touch

Tags: javascript, android, webview, touch

I'm trying to use a webview to display a page that does some very basic canvas animations and displays the current time as a string. I use setTimeout() to update the content once per second (or 30 times per second for the animation).

My problem is that as soon as I touch the screen, my javascript stops executing.

The furthest I have got was adding listeners for touch events to my javascript and call e.preventDefault() in the event handler, which helped in most cases, but seemed to miss some cases for where none of the usual javascript events got fired.

The next thing I tried was to override the default touch handler as follows:

```
myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

This helped, but the problem is that it consumes the touch event before it gets dispatched to my webview, making it impossible to listen for touch events in javascript.

I want to disable all the default Android behavior like zooming and so on, since this is what blocks my animation, but I still want to be able to use these events in javascript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, return false. If you return true, you "say" the event handled.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)